# longtabu: Fine tuning row separation

Tags: tabu, longtabu

Consider this use of the `longtabu` environment from the `tabu` package:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{longtable}

\begin{document}

\begin{longtabu}{lX}
  \toprule
  \textbf{Letter} & \textbf{Description}\\
  \midrule
  \endhead

  \bottomrule
  \endlastfoot

  Alpha & The first Greek letter.\\
  Beta & The second Greek letter.\\
  Gamma & The third Greek letter.
\end{longtabu}

\end{document}
```

This gives me the following table:

[image]

However, I would like to have a greater distance between the rows of the table. If I insert `\tabulinesep=^2mm_2mm` before the table, I get this:

[image]

Here the row spacing is fine, but the spacing also affects the distance between the rules and the text in the heading.

What I really want is headings and rules as in the first example, and row spacing as in the second example. It can be achieved by adding `\addlinespace` after each row in the first example, but this is tedious. Is there a simpler way to achieve what I want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add a negative `\addlinespace` in your header. This is less tedious, I guess.

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{longtable}

\begin{document}
\begin{longtabu}{lX}
    \toprule
    \textbf{Letter} & \textbf{Description}\\
    \midrule
    \endhead        
    \bottomrule
    \endlastfoot
    Alpha & The first Greek letter.\\
    Beta & The second Greek letter.\\
    Gamma & The third Greek letter.
\end{longtabu}  
\tabulinesep=^2mm_2mm
\begin{longtabu}{lX}
    \toprule \addlinespace[-.5mm]
    \textbf{Letter} & \textbf{Description}\\\addlinespace[-1.5mm]
    \midrule
    \endhead        
    \bottomrule
    \endlastfoot
    Alpha & The first Greek letter.\\
    Beta & The second Greek letter.\\
    Gamma & The third Greek letter.
\end{longtabu}  
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Negative `\addlinespace`! Of course. Much better. Thank you.